# Does the DispatcherServlet creates new instance of controller and methods inside for each user?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Good day folks. I have Controller in my application:

```
        @Controller
        public class LoginSearchController {

            //List to store data from resultHTML method
            List<Cars> listCars = null;


            @Autowired
            private EducationWebServiceInterface educationWebService;

                //This method render jsp page for user and create model for resultHTML
                @RequestMapping(value="/search", method=RequestMethod.GET)
                public String search(FormBackingObjectSearch fbos, Model model) {   
                        model.addAttribute("fbosAttributes", fbos);

                    return "search";        
                }   

               //   This method get name form form back object and use it for fetchCarsByNameService method
              // After if something found it stores it in listofSerchObjects and after listofSerchObjects stores it in listForm List
                @RequestMapping(value="/result", method=RequestMethod.GET)
                public String resultHTML(@RequestParam String name,
                                         @ModelAttribute("fbosAttributes") FormBackingObjectSearch fbos, 
                                         BindingResult bindingResut, Model model) throws Exception {


                    listCars = new ArrayList<Cars>();
                    List<Cars> listofSerchObjects = null;

                    listofSerchObjects = educationWebService.fetchCarsByNameService(dateConvertation(fbos.getName()));
                        model.addAttribute("findAttributes", listofSerchObjects);   
                        listCars.addAll(listofSerchObjects);

                    return "search";
                }


                  //This method fetch data from listForm to make Excel document form the list
                @RequestMapping(value="/result.xls", method=RequestMethod.GET)
                public String resultXLS(Model model) throws Exception {

                        if(listCars == null || listCars.size() == 0) {
                            throw new NullPointerException("ArrayList<FormDate> formDateList is empty list");
                        } else {            
                            model.addAttribute("findAttributesXls", listForm);
                        }               
                    return "xlspage";
                }
        }
```

What happens in controller:

User goes on `Search` page fill name of Car he would like to find(in my case) and after click button `FIND`

--> Request goes to `/result`. This  `resultHTML` method invoke `fetchCarsByNameService` from service layer to fetch data corresponding to particular name  to `listofSerchObjects` and render it on jsp page. After when `listofSerchObjects` have data from `fetchCarsByNameService` it will add all data to other list `listCars` .

--> Next step, when all data was rendered on jsp page there is button appears `SAVE AS EXCEL`, what happens: when user click this button(if user want too) it goes to `/result.xls` **AND TAKE ALL THE DATA FROM** `listCars` to save it in Excel file.

I'm very curious  if multiple users will work on the same jsp page  form different computers in my web application,  **how my `listCars` will behave.** I'm scary that it will store last data witch was extracted from DataBase and if user1 want to render it in Excel file that he will have data from user2 if user2 would make search last. What you think??? Give me please advice. Thank you

Comment: Put `List<Cars> listCars = null;` inside `search()` method. This will solve the concurrency issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listCars` is corrupted and may even throw `ConcurrentModificationException` sporadically.

Below are the workarounds for the issue.

1. Make `listCars` a local variable.

   *or*
2. Annotate your `Controller` with `@Scope("session")`

Here is an excellent [blog](http://richardchesterwood.blogspot.in/2011/03/using-sessions-in-spring-mvc-including.html) which describes `Scope` of `Controller` and its pros and cons.

Comment: Yes Sir I did annotate it with @Scope("session"), the next question how it will react on my application if each user will have new instance of controller??

Comment: @UDS Are you talking about performance? If so, Its already listed in the blog. If not, your data is no more shared between users, you are safe!

Answer (score 2):

Your `listCars` instance will be shared between every user because you made it a class level variable.  Since every user (and request) will get its own Thread, that class level variable will be shared between all of them, and likely your data will be corrupted, depending on how fast requests come in.

Comment: Sir,What can you suggest about this problem??

Answer (score 1):

A `@Controller` is a Spring bean, and it'll only get instantiated once by the container. Keep any variables that relate to specific requests on the stack (declared inside the method).

Comment: Sir,What can you suggest about this problem??

Comment: Declare `listCars` inside your `result` methods. You'll need to rerun your search when you export to XLS.

Comment: yes Sir I understand, problem is that I can not return it to my XLS method, @ModelAttributes on argument doesn't work, HttpServlet getAttributes and setAttributes also not. I'm fetching 0. Could you please point me what I have to read or something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The listCars will be shared between all users of the application.

The two invocations for /result and /result.xls are completely independent of each other.  You'll need to lookup the cars list again or pass the listCars into this method as a parameter. You could also store the listCars into the user's session and retrieve it during the result.xls call, but that does pollute the session with unneeded data that may never be used.

Depending on how large listCars is likely to be and how expensive fetchCarsByNameService is should determine whether you pass the list back in as a parameter or just pass in the same parameters as /result and rerun the method.  I'd probably lean towards rerunning the method and having some kind of cache on fetchCarsByNameService if the operation is expensive.

Comment: Sir, your explanation is so amazing, you know I will always get not more than 40 values every time. Please tell me how can I pass list back as a parameter(just it got me a little confused, because usually it will pass list as attributes), just tell me please where to read about this. And yes I kind a don't want to invoke the same service layer in result.xls, but I can do this if I won't have choice. Thanks